# NSMutableDictionary not calling 'release' upon removing object

Tags: objective-c, oop, nsmutabledictionary, ownership

From what I have understood, `NSMutableDictionary` releases all objects when released itself. I wrote a test for this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    @autoreleasepool 
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        NSObject *object = [[NSObject alloc] init];
        [dictionary setObject:object forKey:@"key"];
        [dictionary release];

        NSLog(@"%@", object);
    }
}
```

However, the object still exists, and has not been deallocated:

```
2014-02-15 09:34:31.883 Untitled[15548:707] <NSObject: 0x7fa0b9c09c60>
```

Why is this so?

Comment: Try dumping the retain count in that last case.

Comment: what are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done an alloc & init on your "`object`".  That makes the retain count 1.

When you add it to your dictionary, that makes the retain count 2.

When you release the dictionary, the retain count of the object is decremented to 1.

Which is why you can print out the "contents" of it, since "`object`" has a retain count of 1 and has not been truly released yet.

Comment: call `[object release];` before NSLog and prepare for a crash (since the object is now gone).  Or you can call "`release`" *after* NSLog and you won't crash.

Comment: @AaronBrager that's certainly the case for explicitly *autoreleased* objects but does memory get magically released when regular retained objects fall out of scope?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann No, your comment is correct (I deleted my incorrect comment).